# How does the Iterable.expand(Iterable Function(dynamic) f) function works in Dart?

Tags: function, dart, iterable

As per the example from the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Iterable/expand.html):

```
var pairs = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
var flattened = pairs.expand((pair) => pair).toList();
print(flattened); // => [1, 2, 3, 4];

var input = [1, 2, 3];
var duplicated = input.expand((i) => [i, i]).toList();
print(duplicated); // => [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

It looks like it flattens an iterable if it contains nested iterables, but how is the question.

Comment: "how is the question" ... That question isn't very clear.  Do you want to know its specific implementation (i.e. you want to see its code), do you want to know specific details about its behavior (i.e. whether it flattens iterables nested an arbitrary amount), or do you want to know how you might implement something similar?

Comment: @jamesdlin yeah I wanted to know how it works behind the scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it basically does is that, it iterates over the iterable calling the argument function on each iteration and concatenating the iterables returned by the argument function once the iteration is over and lastly returning the result of the concatenation which is an iterable.

That was a summary on how it works, let's understand it using the example from the documentation itself:

```
var pairs = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
var flattened = pairs.expand((pair) => pair).toList();
print(flattened); // => [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Here we have an iterable `pairs` and we called the `expand()` method on it. Now the `expand()` method will iterate over `pairs` calling the argument function which is `(pair) => pair` once per iteration.

Note that the syntax of the `expand()` method look like this `Iterable<T> expand<T>(Iterable<T> f(T element))` which clearly shows that it takes a function as an argument which takes an argument of type `T` and returns an iterable. e.g.`(pair) => pair` where the `pair` is of type `List<int>`

As of now we are clear that the `expand()` method iterates over an iterable calling the argument function on each iteration. The argument function takes an argument which is of same type as the iterable and it returns an iterable.

Lastly, the `expand()` method concatenates the iterables returned by the argument function once the iteration on the iterable e.g. `pairs` is over `[1, 2] + [3, 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4]`. Then it returns the result of the concatenation which is an iterable `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically just a loop within a loop that iterates into each iterable, finds each inner element of the inner iterable, then returns it as a single stretched out iterable.

I can't find source code for `expand`, but in my [darq](https://pub.dev/packages/darq) package, you can see the same concept in action using the `selectMany` method (which is because `selectMany` is just `expand` with an additional index passed to the selector). For how Dart's `expand` works, ignore all the parts that deal with `index`.

```dart
extension SelectManyExtension<T> on Iterable<T> {
  /// Maps elements in an iterable to collections and then flattens those
  /// collections into a single iterable.
  ///
  /// During iteration, the [selector] function is provided each value in the iterable
  /// along with the index of the value in the iteration. The
  /// returned collection of that function is then iterated over, and each
  /// value in that iteration is provided as the next element of the
  /// resulting iterable. The result is all of the collections flattened so that
  /// their values become elements in a single iterable.
  ///
  /// Example:
  ///
  ///     void main() {
  ///       final list = ['abc', 'de', 'f', 'ghij'];
  ///       final result = list.selectMany((s, i) => s.iterable);
  ///
  ///       // Result: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
  ///     }
  Iterable<TResult> selectMany<TResult>(
      Iterable<TResult> Function(T element, int index) selector) sync* {
    var index = 0;
    for (var v in this) {
      yield* selector(v, index++);
    }
  }
}
```

```dart
var list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
var flattened = list.selectMany((inner, idx) => inner);

// flattened = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```